# job offer with start date

Tags: job-offer

I have been offered a job with a start date of 2nd of June which I accepted.I was told company would get in touch on 29th of May with details.I have not heard back from Company. What should I do.?

Comment: You need to ring them and speak with someone as soon as possible.

Comment: 2nd of June, you mean tomorrow? Just call them. Tell them you're supposed to stary tomorrow. Tell them you were told that they will get in touch with you for more details, that's why you're calling. They probably forgot so just call them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I hope that offer was in writing.  If not, continue your job search on the off chance that this doesn't pan out.  You're not done job hunting until you've cashed your first paycheck, and sometimes not even then.

Answer (score 2):

As they gave you a definite date, what you *should* have done is to contact them on the 30th (or late on the 29th) politely enquiring about the status of the offer. As you didn't do that, you're in a bit of a bind as you're now going to need to be at least slightly pushy about it.

Pick up the phone and try and get through to whoever made you the offer ASAP. If you don't have their direct number, phone the office and explain to whoever picks up the phone what the situation is. If you really can't do that, use whatever means of communication you do have.